# Elasticsearch basic mapping fails

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I've installed the Docker containers for Elasticsearch 5.5.2 and Kibana. I started to learn about mapping types, and created an index with the following code through xcurl:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "user": { 
      "_all":       { "enabled": false  }, 
      "properties": { 
        "title":    { "type": "text"  }, 
        "name":     { "type": "text"  }, 
        "age":      { "type": "integer" }  
      }
    }
}
```

The index was created successfully and I decided to insert some data. When I try to add a string into an integer field `i.e. {"age": "hello"}`, Elastic shows an error (this means mappings is working OK). The problem is with other data types:

1.It accepts integers and floats in string fields (I think this could be because of implicit casts).

2.It accepts floats like `22.4` in the `age`field (when I search with Kibana or xcurl the `age`field content is shown as float and not as an integer, that means is not doing casts from float to integer)

What I'm doing bad?

Comment: Can you describe how you're inserting the documents?

Comment: For the first part of your question; `22.2` is a perfectly valid string. Strings are just not regular letters, it can be anything. The difference is that a `text` field is analyzed and tokenized differently from other fields.

Comment: @aclokay `curl -XPOST localhost:9200/my_index/user -d '{"title":"A title", "name":"username","age":223.5}'`                  and it returns                      
            `{
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "user",
  "_id" : "AV4JO3pZh8gyIWsivJ6d",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "created" : true
}
`

Comment: @MatsLindh Even if I don't specify it with double quotes? I'm inserting `22.2` instead of `"22.2"` and it accepts the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to disable coercion? It can be done at field level:

```
   {
     "mappings": {
       "user": { 
         "_all":       { "enabled": false  }, 
         "properties": { 
           "title":    { "type": "text"  }, 
           "name":     { "type": "text"  }, 
           "age":      { "type": "integer",
                         "coerce": false}  
         }
       }
   }
```

Or at index level for all fields:

```
   "settings": {
       "index.mapping.coerce": false
     },
     "mappings": {
   ...
```

Comment: It ran ok. Thanks @Imma :)